# Cauchy Integral Formula on a triangle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

In the exercise questions(just exercise not homework) for a Complex analysis course we are asked the following;

Suppose we have $f$ analytic on the disc $D(0,2)$ show that;
$$
\int_C\frac{f(w)}{w-i/2}\text{d}w = 
\int_{\Delta}\frac{f(w)}{w-i/2}\text{d}w.
$$

Where $C$ is the unit circle centered at zero, counter clockwise, and $\Delta$ is the triangle, counter clockwise, with corners $i,\pm 1-i$.

Here is what I have so far;

Since $f$ is analytic on $D(0,2)$, Cauchy's integral applies formula to $C$ and since and $i/2$ in the interior of $C$ we have

$$
f(i/2)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(w)}{w-i/2}\text{d}w.
$$

So it is sufficient to show that

$$
f(i/2)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\Delta}\frac{f(w)}{w-i/2}\text{d}w.
$$

But now consider the difference quotient
$$
g(i/2) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{f(w)-f(i/2)}{w-i/2},& w\neq i/2\\
f'(i/2)&w=i/2
\end{cases}
$$

Now one can show that $g$ is analytic on the disc $D(0,2)$ and so by the closed curve theorem we know
$$
\int_{\Delta}\frac{f(w)-f(i/2)}{w-i/2}\text{d}w = 0
$$
which gives

$$
\int_{\Delta}\frac{f(w)}{w-i/2}\text{d}w = f(i/2)\int_{\Delta}\frac{1}{w-i/2}\text{d}w 
$$
So it is sufficient to show that
$$
\int_{\Delta}\frac{1}{w-i/2}\text{d}w = 2\pi i
$$

Now since  $|i/2|<w$, for $w$ on $\Delta$ we have that $\frac{|i/2|}{|w|}<1$

$$
\frac{1}{w-i/2} = \frac{1}{w}\frac{1}{1-\frac{i}{2w}}=\frac{1}{w}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{i}{2w}\bigg)^k
$$

and the power series converges uniformly so we can write

$$
\int_{\Delta}\frac{1}{w-i/2}\text{d}w =\frac{1}{w}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{\Delta}\bigg(\frac{i}{2w}\bigg)^k.
$$
But now for each $k\geq 1$ we have that $\frac{-1}{kw^k}$ is the analytic anti-derivative of $\frac{1}{k^{k+1}}$ and so by the closed curve theorem we have

$$
\int_{\Delta}\frac{1}{w-i/2}\text{d}w = \int_{\Delta}\frac{1}{w}dw.
$$

AAAAANDD... now i'm stuck. Im not sure how to show that this integral is equal to $2\pi i$... I have a feeling we need the complex logarithm, but we haven't learnt that yet.

Have I made any mistakes in the working above? Is there a way forward that does not need the complex logarith? Do we even need the complex logarithm?

Cheers in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you mean "triangle" or "square"? If it is a triangle with vertices $1,i,-i$, your path of integration goes through the singularity.

Comment: It has vertices i, -1-i and 1-i so we dont have to worry about going through the singularity

Comment: Of course, sorry, I imagined an extra comma that wasn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easier approach that avoids computing the integrals and using Cauchy's integral formula.
You can draw a picture of $C$ and $\Delta$ and then notice that $\int_C-\int_\Delta$ is the same as the sum over four integrals over certain closed contours. Each of these contours lies in a half-disk where the function $z\mapsto \frac{f(z)}{z-i/2}$ is analytic, so integrals over those contours are zero, and so the original integrals coincide.

Comment: That is way easier. Thank you